# How to convert sidebar to hamburger menu in small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have side menu that i need to convert it to hamburger menu when the screen is small mobile sized.

I think all the content between `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">` gets into hamburger.

```html
<!Doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <!-- Required meta tags -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
          <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
          <title>Admin</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ADMIN PANEL</a>
             <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
             </button>
             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- code here will be displayed in hamburger -->
             </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 ">
                   <ul class="list-group bg-primary ">
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0  p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 1 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 2 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 3 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 4 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 5 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 6 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 7 </a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                   My Content
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
          <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/zgj15ads/ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use bootstrap [utility display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/)

This is a solution to your problem.

```html
 <!Doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
           <head>
              <!-- Required meta tags -->
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
              <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
              <title>Admin</title>
           </head>
           <body>
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ADMIN PANEL</a>
                 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                 </button>
                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="list-group bg-primary d-block d-sm-none">
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0  p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 1 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 2 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 3 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 4 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 5 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 6 </a></li>
                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 7 </a></li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="container-fluid">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3 d-none d-sm-block">
                       <ul class="list-group bg-primary ">
                          <li class="list-unstyled  border-0  p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 1 </a></li>
                          <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 2 </a></li>
                          <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 3 </a></li>
                          <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 4 </a></li>
                          <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 5 </a></li>
                          <li class="list-unstyled  border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 6 </a></li>
                          <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 7 </a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                       My Content
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
              <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: sir this worked but there are some padding in left side of menu how to remove it?

Comment: There is padding set to navbar class. You can remove it with the utilty classes [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/) and add spacing to navbar-brand and navbar-toggler

Comment: Thank you @Gergana, this has been very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solution of Gergana I have further improved it.
Now the left bar is full screen, there are no paddings, and the layout it's a bit improved.
Please vote also Gergana solution since she put the milestone for this one.

```html
<!Doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
           <head>
              <!-- Required meta tags -->
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
              <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
              <title>Admin</title>
           </head>
           <body>

              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-3 d-none d-sm-block p-0 bg-secondary p-3 min-vh-100">
                          <h4 class="gray-3">Right bar</h4>
                          <ul class="list-group mt-4">
                              <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-light">Product 1 </a></li>
                              <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-light">Product 2 </a></li>
                              <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-light">Product 3 </a></li>
                              <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-light">Product 4 </a></li>
                              <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-light">Product 5 </a></li>
                              <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-light">Product 6 </a></li>
                              <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-light">Product 7 </a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 p-0">
                          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
                              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ADMIN PANEL</a>
                              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                  <ul class="list-group bg-primary d-block d-sm-none">
                                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 1 </a></li>
                                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 2 </a></li>
                                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 3 </a></li>
                                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 4 </a></li>
                                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 5 </a></li>
                                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 6 </a></li>
                                      <li class="list-unstyled border-0 p-2"> <a href="" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </i>   Product 7 </a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </div>
                          </nav>
                          <main class="p-4">
                              My Content
                          </main>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
              <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           </body>
        </html>
```